# Implementation of rational numbers in Idris

Tags: idris, rational-numbers

Are there any existing implementations of rational numbers in Idris?

E.g. `Data.Ratio` ports from Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a quick search, I found [this](https://github.com/mcgordonite/idris-binary-rationals), if it could be interesting